# getting runtime statistics with monitoredtrainingsession in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, statistics, runtime, profile

I am trying to get my tensorflow code profile (running and memory consumption of each layers in the network) by following the runtime statistics instruction [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz#runtime_statistics). As far as I understand, I need to create run options and run metadata like this

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
```

and pass them to `sess.run`

However, as I am also trying to use `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` I don't know if I can pass the same thing into this class. A plausible approach could make use of Hooks but I do not know how to do it. I am still very new to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a custom hook and pass it to the `MonitoredTrainingSession`. There is no need to pass your own `tf.RunMetadata()` instance to the run call.

Here is an example Hook which stores metadata every N steps to ckptdir:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class TraceHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    """Hook to perform Traces every N steps."""

    def __init__(self, ckptdir, every_step=50, trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE):
        self._trace = every_step == 1
        self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(ckptdir)
        self.trace_level = trace_level
        self.every_step = every_step

    def begin(self):
        self._global_step_tensor = tf.train.get_global_step()
        if self._global_step_tensor is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Global step should be created to use _TraceHook.")

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        if self._trace:
            options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=self.trace_level)
        else:
            options = None
        return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(fetches=self._global_step_tensor,
                                       options=options)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
        global_step = run_values.results - 1
        if self._trace:
            self._trace = False
            self.writer.add_run_metadata(run_values.run_metadata,
                                         f'{global_step}', global_step)
        if not (global_step + 1) % self.every_step:
            self._trace = True
```

It checks in `before_run` whether it has to trace or not and if so, adds the RunOptions. In `after_run` it checks if the next run call needs to be traced and if so, it sets `_trace` to True again. Additionally it stores the metadata when it is available.